como soluciono el mapeo en spring boot?
Hola estoy iniciando a usar spring boot y quiero usar un orm h2 y tengo mi controlador pero al acceder a la ruta me sale el siguiente mensaje

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No static
resource users

Este es mi clase controlador
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; // Repositorio de usuarios para acceder a la base de datos


    // Controlador para la página de lista de usuarios
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
          model.addAttribute("usuarios", userRepository.findAll()); // Agrega todos los usuarios al modelo
          return "users"; // Devuelve el nombre de la plantilla Thymeleaf para la lista de usuarios
    }
}

y me dice que por que no encuentra o no existe pero sí la tengo.

estas son mis dependencias
<dependencies>
     <!-- Core dependencies for Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web for web applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA for JPA and Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 Database for in-memory database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf for template engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Validation for Bean Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons FileUpload for handling file uploads -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


Buen día. ¿Podrías compartir el pom.xml o el build.gradle de tu aplicación? Quizás te hace falta alguna dependencia.

Como te indica Fernando, para usar Thymeleaf tienes que añadir la dependencia y además las plantillas tienen que estar localizadas en un directorio específico: src/main/resources/templates. Aquí puedes encontrar un ejemplo sencillo. ¿Puedes verificar que tienes las dependencias adecuadas y que hay un fichero users.html en el directorio indicado?

Ya intenaste reemplazar @Controller con @RestController? Adicionalmente agrega el paquete para tener un [mcve] y donde está tu clase que tiene el main
